# Load a DIV on top of another when a DIV is called

Tags: javascript, html, overlay

Well, I have this Slide with three panels:

DIV 1, DIV 2, DIV 3.

- DIV 1 has id=slide-one
- DIV 2 has id=slide-two
- DIV 3 has id=slide-three

> There are navi buttons: Id1, Id2, Id3.

The function that I'm am wondering is, if its possible When Id1 calls DIV1 and DIV1 slides in, is it possible to load a DIV-new on top of DIV1?
as in when DIV1 is called, it loads a DIV-new on top of it.
Same for DIV 2 & DIV 3.
Please refer to [this html](http://www.temzlemdor.in/Slide.html) to get the example of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use `position:absolute` and a `z-index`.

That is,

```
element.style.position = 'absolute';
element.style.zIndex = 10;
```

...and make sure the bottom `<div>` has a lower z-index.  Also, life will be easier if the parent of the absolute `<div>` has a `position:relative` style.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Steve. I'll try that out right away. So the DIV-new that loads on top of DIV1 will not be visible right?
As in it will load only when DIV1 is called?
Would appreciate it if you can give some input on that

Comment: Whenever the div is created (via JS or via the HTML markup) you can use `style.display = 'none'; // or 'block'` to toggle its visibility.  (or, `display:block` in CSS).

Comment: No problemo, glad to help, welcome to SO.  Another tip that may help is `childElement.style.height = parentElement.offsetHeight + 'px'` and `.offsetWidth` with which you could match the size of the parent element, if necessary.

Comment: Hi @Steve,
Well, I tried to implement the functions through CSS.
I gave the DIV-new

`position:absolute; z-index:3;background-color:#eee; display:block; width:inherit; height:inherit`


Well, the DIV-new does come up when ID1 calls DIV1 and DIV1 slides in.
however, it remains visible the entire time whether it is called or not.
I'm not much of a coder when it comes to javascript so is it possible to help me out on that?
If i'm not asking too much

Comment: DIV1 has `z-index:2;position:relative`

Comment: If a `DIV` running exactly underneath another `DIV` has a higher `z-index` it will always be visible over the other. Why not,as @Steve suggests, I believe, toggle visibility or display? That can be achieved with a simple iff I'm not mistaken:~)

Comment: @Roberto Is it possible to toggle visibility Using only CSS without javascript?

Comment: @TemzLemz: WARNING- I'm self taught on HTML, CSS, & JScript. Not as far as I know. Newer standards have better capability soo.. maybe? Changing the `id` could also work, but script is probably easiest -  that's why it's used. You don't have to have CSS, but why not; right?

Comment: Ok. I'm just in need if someone could assist me on this query. as i'm not that good with Javascript....with CSS itself, i think it will be posible. Is there a way where i can implement the above way Steve showed?
I'm sorry if i seem too pushy